# How can I a foreign key to NULL in SQL Server database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to get your advice about how i can add foreign key constraint with set null.

I wrote this SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE DEPARTMENT
ADD CONSTRAINT DEPARTMENT_HIDEPTID_FK 
    FOREIGN KEY (HIDEPTID) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(DEPTID) 
    SET NULL
```

but, at the end of the above statement, `set null` causes an error.

I can add just foreign key, but with set null, I cannot.

Thank you.

Comment: Hint:  `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

Comment: why you want to set null value ? also provide your table structure

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your hint.

```
ALTER TABLE DEPARTMENT
    ADD CONSTRAINT DEPARTMENT_HIDEPTID_FK 
        FOREIGN KEY(HIDEPTID) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(DEPTID) 
            ON DELETE CASCADE
```

This works.

The reason I'd like to set null at foreign key is that the table references itself.

Thank you.

Comment: Then just use `ON DELETE SET NULL` - you are just missing the `ON DELETE` (or `ON UPDATE`) clause in your original SQL